# How do I pipe the output of a unix command to a Julia script?

Tags: unix, pipe, julia

I'm trying to utilize the `STDIN` construct with Julia to read in the output of a unix command:

```
#!/usr/bin/julia
readline(STDIN)
```

Then in my terminal:

```
$ cat myfile.txt | ./pipe.jl
```

but I am not getting any output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the result of `readline(STDIN)`.  What kind of output do you want?

Unlike the interactive REPL, a Julia script won't automatically print results.  You need to explicitly `print` the resulting string:

```
print(readline(STDIN))
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
#!/usr/bin/julia
```

Has to be first, as Unix reads **only** the first line and checks it for `#!`. Also, you need to do:

```
chmod +x pipe.jl
```

To make it work from `./pipe.jl` construct.

Comment: It is... I added the filename only here